# C# SharpDX how to set texture coordinates correctly?

Tags: c#, sharpdx, direct3d11

I am trying to render texture on a cube. However, I do something wrong. I have the texture but coordinates looks like wrong and I do not know how to set it correctly. What am I missing ? I think I must do something about IndexBuffer and UV. However, my mind is very mixed.

The result I get :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fdJAaU81sQ

Mesh.cs

```
 public class Mesh : IDisposable
    {
        public string File;
        public string Name;
        public Vector4[] Vertices { get; set; }
        public int VerticesCount=0;
        public Vector3 Position; //BASED ON PIVOT
        public Vector3 PivotPosition; //MOVE MESH BASED ON THIS POSITION
        public Vector3 Rotation;
        public double Weight;
        public SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device d3dDevice;
        public SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer VerticesBuffer;

        public bool IsDisposed=false;
        public bool IsSelected = false;
        public int Triangles;
        public string Texture_DiffuseMap;                

        public Mesh(string _name, Vector4[] _vertices, string _file, SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device _device, string _Texture_DiffuseMap = "")
        {
            Vertices = new[]
            {
                new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Front
                new Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // BACK
                new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // Top
                new Vector4(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Bottom
                new Vector4( 1.0f,-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f,-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f,-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // Left
                new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // Right
                new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
            };
            Texture_DiffuseMap = _Texture_DiffuseMap;
            _vertices = Vertices;
            d3dDevice = _device;
            VerticesCount = Vertices.Count();

            Name = _name;
            File = _file;
            Meshes.Add(this);
        }

        // Other functions go here...

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            IsDisposed = true;

        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Dispose();
            }
            // free native resources if there are any.
            VerticesBuffer.Dispose();
            IsDisposed = true;
        }

        public void Render()
        {

            d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList;
            d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(VerticesBuffer, Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() * 2, 0));


            d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.Draw(VerticesCount,0);


            /*d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.LineList;

            d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(VerticesBuffer, Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() * 2, 0));

            d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.Draw(VerticesCount, 0);
            */
            VerticesBuffer.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
            [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            DisposeCollector DC=new DisposeCollector();
            var form = new RenderForm(Globals.Window_Title) { Width = Globals.Window_Size.Width, Height = Globals.Window_Size.Height, AllowUserResizing = false, MinimizeBox = false };
            InputHandler IHandler = new InputHandler(form);
            SampleDescription SamplerDesc = new SampleDescription(8, 0);
            // SwapChain description
            var desc = new SwapChainDescription()
            {
                BufferCount = 2,
                ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
                IsWindowed = true,
                OutputHandle = form.Handle,
                SampleDescription = SamplerDesc,
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            };

            var samplerStateDescription = new SamplerStateDescription
            {
                AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
                AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
                AddressW = TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
                Filter = Filter.MinMagMipLinear
            };
            var rasterizerStateDescription = RasterizerStateDescription.Default();
            rasterizerStateDescription.IsFrontCounterClockwise = true;

            // Used for debugging dispose object references
            Configuration.EnableObjectTracking = true;

            // Disable throws on shader compilation errors
            Configuration.ThrowOnShaderCompileError = false;

            SharpDX.DXGI.Factory factory = new SharpDX.DXGI.Factory1();
            SharpDX.DXGI.Adapter adapter = factory.GetAdapter(1);

            Adapter[] availableAdapters = factory.Adapters;
            foreach(Adapter _adapter in availableAdapters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(_adapter.Description.Description);
            }
            // Create Device and SwapChain
            Device device;
            SwapChain swapChain;
            Device.CreateWithSwapChain(adapter, DeviceCreationFlags.SingleThreaded, desc, out device, out swapChain);

            var context = device.ImmediateContext;

            //factory.MakeWindowAssociation(form.Handle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

            // Compile Vertex and Pixel shaders
            var vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniCube.hlsl", "VS", "vs_5_0", ShaderFlags.Debug);
            var vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, vertexShaderByteCode);

            var pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniCube.hlsl", "PS", "ps_5_0", ShaderFlags.Debug);
            var pixelShader = new PixelShader(device, pixelShaderByteCode);

            var signature = ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(vertexShaderByteCode);

            // Layout from VertexShader input signature
            var layout = new InputLayout(device, signature, new[]
            {
            new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0),
            new InputElement("NORMAL", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0),
            new InputElement("COLOR", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 16, 0),
            new InputElement("TEXCOORD", 0, Format.R32G32_Float, InputElement.AppendAligned, 0)

            });

            var samplerState = new SamplerState(device, samplerStateDescription);

            Mesh mesh1 = new Mesh("mesh1", new[] { new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1) }, "", device, "1_Purple.jpg") { IsSelected=true };
            Mesh mesh2 = new Mesh("mesh2", new[] { new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1) }, "", device, "1_GREEN.jpg");
            //MenuCreator menu1 = new MenuCreator(device,new[] {new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 0) });
            // Create Constant Buffer
            var contantBuffer = new Buffer(device, Utilities.SizeOf<Matrix>(), ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.ConstantBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);

            ShaderResourceView textureView;
            SharpDX.WIC.ImagingFactory2 ImagingFactory2 = new SharpDX.WIC.ImagingFactory2();

            // Prepare All the stages
            context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = layout;


            context.VertexShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, contantBuffer);
            context.VertexShader.Set(vertexShader);
            context.PixelShader.Set(pixelShader);
            context.PixelShader.SetSampler(0, samplerState);
            //context.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, textureView);

            Matrix proj = Matrix.Identity;

            // Use clock
            var clock = new Stopwatch();
            FPS fps = new FPS();
            clock.Start();

            // Declare texture for rendering
            bool userResized = true;
            Texture2D backBuffer = null;
            RenderTargetView renderView = null;
            Texture2D depthBuffer = null;
            DepthStencilView depthView = null;

            // Setup handler on resize form
            form.UserResized += (sender, args) => userResized = true;

            // Setup full screen mode change F5 (Full) F4 (Window)
            form.KeyUp += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (args.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
                swapChain.SetFullscreenState(true, null);
                else if (args.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
                    swapChain.SetFullscreenState(false, null);
                else if (args.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
                    form.Close();
            };

            //CREATE DEPTH STENCIL DESCRIPTION
            DepthStencilStateDescription depthSSD = new DepthStencilStateDescription();
            depthSSD.IsDepthEnabled = false;
            depthSSD.DepthComparison = Comparison.LessEqual;
            depthSSD.DepthWriteMask = DepthWriteMask.Zero;
            DepthStencilState DSState = new DepthStencilState(device, depthSSD);

            Camera camera = new Camera();
            camera.eye = new Vector3(0, 0, -5);
            camera.target = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            Globals.Render = true;
            /*void DrawEmptyCircle(Vector3 startPoint, Vector2 radius, Color color)
            {
                List<VertexPositionColor> circle = new List<VertexPositionColor>();
                float X, Y;

                var stepDegree = 0.3f;
                for (float angle = 0; angle <= 360; angle += stepDegree)
                {
                    X = startPoint.X + radius.X * (float)Math.Cos((angle));
                    Y = startPoint.Y + radius.Y * (float)Math.Sin((angle));
                    Vector3 point = new Vector3(X, Y, 0);
                    circle.Add(new VertexPositionColor(point, color));
                }
            }*/
            CubeApp.Windows.SystemInformation.Print(CubeApp.Windows.SystemInformation.GetSystemInformation());
            HardwareInformation.GetHardwareInformation("Win32_DisplayConfiguration", "Description");

            // Main loop
            RenderLoop.Run(form, () =>
            {


                    fps.Count();fps.setFormHeader(form);
                // Prepare matrices
                if (Globals.Render)
                {
                    var view = camera.getView();

                // If Form resized
                if (userResized)
                {
                    // Dispose all previous allocated resources
                    Utilities.Dispose(ref backBuffer);
                    Utilities.Dispose(ref renderView);
                    Utilities.Dispose(ref depthBuffer);
                    Utilities.Dispose(ref depthView);

                        foreach (Mesh _mesh in Meshes.MeshCollection)
                    {
                        if (_mesh.IsDisposed == false)
                        {
                            Utilities.Dispose(ref _mesh.VerticesBuffer);
                        }
                    }

                        // Resize the backbuffer
                        swapChain.ResizeBuffers(desc.BufferCount, form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, Format.Unknown, SwapChainFlags.None);
                        // Get the backbuffer from the swapchain
                        backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0);
                        // Renderview on the backbuffer
                        renderView = new RenderTargetView(device, backBuffer);
                        // Create the depth buffer
                        depthBuffer = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription()
                        {
                            Format = Format.D32_Float_S8X24_UInt,
                            ArraySize = 1,
                            MipLevels = 1,
                            Width = form.ClientSize.Width,
                            Height = form.ClientSize.Height,
                            SampleDescription = SamplerDesc,
                            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
                            BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil,
                            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
                            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None
                        });

                        // Create the depth buffer view
                        depthView = new DepthStencilView(device, depthBuffer);
                        // Setup targets and viewport for rendering
                        context.Rasterizer.SetViewport(new Viewport(0, 0, form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, 0.0f, 1.0f));
                        //context.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(DSState);
                        context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(depthView, renderView);
                        // Setup new projection matrix with correct aspect ratio
                        proj = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH((float)Math.PI / 4.0f, form.ClientSize.Width / (float)form.ClientSize.Height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
                        // We are done resizing
                        userResized = false;
                    }
                    var time = clock.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0f;
                    var viewProj = Matrix.Multiply(view, proj);

            // Clear views
            context.ClearDepthStencilView(depthView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);
            context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Color.WhiteSmoke);

            // Update WorldViewProj Matrix
            var worldViewProj = Matrix.RotationX(45) * Matrix.RotationY(0 * 2) * Matrix.RotationZ(0 * .7f) * viewProj;
            worldViewProj.Transpose();
            context.UpdateSubresource(ref worldViewProj, contantBuffer);

                //Update Camera Position
                Vector3 _camEye = camera.eye;
                Vector3 _camTarget = camera.target;

                if (IHandler.KeyW)
                {
                    _camEye.Z+= 0.050f; _camTarget.Z += 0.050f;
                }
                if (IHandler.KeyS)
                {
                    _camEye.Z -= 0.050f; _camTarget.Z -= 0.050f;
                }
                if (IHandler.KeyA)
                {
                        _camEye.X -= 0.050f; _camTarget.X -= 0.050f;

                }
                if (IHandler.KeyD)
                {
                    _camTarget.X += 0.050f;
                    _camEye.X += 0.050f;

                }
                if (IHandler.KeyQ)
                {

                }
                camera.eye = _camEye;
                camera.target = _camTarget;
                camera.updateView();

                // Draw the cube
                foreach (Mesh __mesh in Meshes.MeshCollection)
                {
                    if ( __mesh.IsSelected )
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= __mesh.VerticesCount - 1; i++)
                        {
                            if (IHandler.KeyRight) __mesh.Vertices[i].X += 0.050f;
                            if (IHandler.KeyLeft) __mesh.Vertices[i].X -= 0.050f;
                            if (IHandler.KeyUp) __mesh.Vertices[i].Y += 0.050f;
                            if (IHandler.KeyDown) __mesh.Vertices[i].Y -= 0.050f;
                        }
                }
                        var texture = TextureLoader.CreateTexture2DFromBitmap(device, TextureLoader.LoadBitmap(ImagingFactory2, __mesh.Texture_DiffuseMap));
                        textureView = new ShaderResourceView(device, texture);

                        context.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, textureView);
                        texture.Dispose();
                        textureView.Dispose();
                        __mesh.VerticesBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, __mesh.Vertices);
                    //EnvironmentDisplayModes.SetDisplayMode(device, __mesh, EnvironmentDisplayModes.DisplayMode.Standart);
                    __mesh.Render();
            }

            // Present!
            swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
                }
            });
            // Release all resources
            foreach (Mesh msh in Meshes.MeshCollection)
            {
                msh.d3dDevice.Dispose();
                msh.VerticesBuffer.Dispose();
            }
        DC.DisposeAndClear();
        signature.Dispose();
        vertexShaderByteCode.Dispose();
        vertexShader.Dispose();
        pixelShaderByteCode.Dispose();
        pixelShader.Dispose();
        layout.Dispose();
        contantBuffer.Dispose();
        depthBuffer.Dispose();
        depthView.Dispose();
        renderView.Dispose();
        backBuffer.Dispose();
        ImagingFactory2.Dispose();
        device.Dispose();
        context.Dispose();
        swapChain.Dispose();
        factory.Dispose();
        adapter.Dispose();
        DSState.Dispose();
        samplerState.Dispose();
        DC.Dispose();
        form.Dispose();
        })).Start();   
}
}
```

MiniCube.hlsl

```
Texture2D ShaderTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState Sampler : register(s0);

struct VS_IN
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float3 Normal : NORMAL;
    float4 col : COLOR;
    float2 TextureUV: TEXCOORD; // Texture UV coordinate
};
struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 pos : POSITION0;
    float depth : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 TextureUV: TEXCOORD;
};

struct PS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
    float2 TextureUV: TEXCOORD;
    float3 WorldNormal : NORMAL;
    float3 WorldPosition : WORLDPOS;
};

float4x4 worldViewProj;

PS_IN VS( VS_IN input )
{
    PS_IN output = (PS_IN)0;

    output.pos = mul(input.pos, worldViewProj);
    input.pos.z= input.pos.z - 0.9f;
    input.pos.z *= 10.0f;

    output.col = 1.0f-((input.pos.w /* * input.col*/) / (input.pos.z /* *input.col*/));
    output.TextureUV = input.TextureUV;
    return output;
}

float4 PS( PS_IN input ) : SV_Target
{
    return ShaderTexture.Sample(Sampler, input.TextureUV)*input.col;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is common to store the texture coordinates in the vertices.
So the first thing to do for you is to change your structure of your vertices to:

```
public MyVertex
{ 
     public Vector3 Position;
     public Vector3 Normal;
     public Vector2 TextureCoord;
}
```

I do not see the necessity to make the position and normal a vector4, so this should do it. As you use textures there is also no need to use color in the vertex structure.

Next you change your input structure for the shader to the above structure. In the shader but also in your intialization of it.

It is recommended that you set the texture coordinates in the initialization of the mesh. An example would be for a plane:

`var vertices = new MyVertex[]
{ 
new MyVertex(){Position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),Normal = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), TextureCoord = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f)},
new MyVertex(){Position = new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),Normal = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), TextureCoord = new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f)},
new MyVertex(){Position = new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),Normal = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), TextureCoord = new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f)},
new MyVertex(){Position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),Normal = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), TextureCoord = new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f)}
};`

If you store your vertices like that, it should work like a charm.
Only thing left to do is, to use the input texturecoordinates for your sampling of the passed texture in the shader.

Also there is no need for manipulation of the texturecoordinates in the shader if you want to use simple texture mapping. Otherwise you can look up different types of texture mapping on wikipedia, like spherical-, box- or plane-texturemapping.